# Sequences of functions Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Data:
interval $I,J$

$f_n(x): I \rightarrow J$
and $\phi$ $ J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

assuming that $f_n\;$ uniform convergence on I

a)Prove that if $\phi$ uniform continuous o J then $\phi\circ f_n \rightrightarrows \phi\circ f\;$  on I

b)give an example, that if $\phi$ just continuous (not uniform) on J then it isn't true

Please help me, how to prove it.

Comment: Is $\,f\,$ the limit of $\,\{f_n\}\,$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of the double arrow?

Comment: Double arrow mean that the sequences of functions is uniform convergent

Comment: I don't think this is standard. It might be better to write "converges uniformly to" for people who are not aware of this notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Take $\epsilon>0$. Use uniform continuity of $\phi$ to get a $\delta>0$. Use uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to make $\|f_n-f\|_\infty=\sup_I|f_n-f|<\delta$. Then check it gives you what you want.

b) Try $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ and $\phi(x)=e^x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Of course, don't take $\phi$ on a compact, given [Heine-Cantor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem).

Comment: Is it good exemple?